# In HTML & CSS, can't properly see my icons in front of my buttons

Tags: html, css

I've tried to create a background which, when hovered over reveals 2 buttons. Each of these buttons should then have a different icon on it.

I've also attempted within css to alter the color of each, of these icons from black to white.

But for some reason I'm not being able to see the full icons infront of the buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/72XyL/225/

**Html:**

```
<div class="show-image">
    <div onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk','mywindow');" style="cursor: hand;" class="update">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk','mywindow');" style="cursor: hand;" class="delete">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.doylecollection.com/var/doyle/storage/images/media/photo-galleries/the-dupont-circle-hotel-gallery/rooms/dupont-circle-hotel-superior-king-room/36016-1-eng-US/dupont-circle-hotel-superior-king-room_gallery_image.jpg" class="background" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.show-image {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
div.show-image:hover img {
    opacity:1;
}
div.show-image:hover div {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
}
div.show-image div {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.background {width:600px;height:400px;}

.update {
    top:45%;
    left:30%;
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: #de543e;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    border-radius: 80px;
    z-index:1;
}
.show-image .update .img{
    background-color:#fff;
    -webkit-mask-image: url('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/MiL/LKL/MiLLKLegT.png');
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    z-index:2000;
}
.show-image .delete .img {
    background-color:#fff;
    -webkit-mask-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/black-white-metro-calendar-icon.png');
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    z-index:2000;
}
.delete {
    top:45%;
    left:55%;
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: #de543e;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    border-radius: 80px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/72XyL/226/ like this

Comment: What you've done doesn't change the icons from black to white using css. Which is a feature I really wanted

Comment: why dont you change the `color` of image to `white` ? using photoshop or image editing tool... make it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would not advise the use of css masks because of [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=masks), in order to solve your problem you need to add to `.show-image .img` the following css:

```
.show-image .img{
    -webkit-mask-position: 0;
    -webkit-mask-size: 24px;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

This answer has in consideration your current code and will obviously work only for webkit browsers.

Comment: I can only accept your answer in 5 minutes. But what you've done has fixed my issue, thanks

Comment: work until you are not considering to support IE browser. check link. http://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-mask

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code using CSS `:before` property.

It will be something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/72XyL/230/

Comment: The icons aren't visible in the jsfiddle above

Answer (score 0):

```
            div.show-image {
            position: relative;
            float:left;
                        margin:5px;
            }
            div.show-image:hover img {
            opacity:1;
            }
            div.show-image:hover div {
            display: block;
            opacity:1;
            }
             div.show-image div {
            position:absolute;
            display:none;
            }
              .background {
            width:600px;
            height:400px;
              }
             .update {
            top:45%;
            left:30%;
            width: 25px;
            height:25px;
            margin-right: 4px;
            background-color: #de543e;
            padding: 16px 18px;
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: 0.9;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
            border-radius: 80px;
            z-index:1;
            }
               .show-image .update .img {
            background: url('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/MiL/LKL/MiLLKLegT.png') no-repeat;
            background-size:25px;
            width: 25px;
            height:25px;
            z-index:2000;
            }
              .show-image .delete .img {
            background: url('http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/black-white-metro-                      calendar-icon.png') no-repeat;
            background-size:25px;
            width: 25px;
            height:25px;
            z-index:2000;
        }
        .delete {
            top:45%;
            left:55%;
            width: 25px;
            height:25px;
            margin-right: 4px;
            background-color: #de543e;
            padding: 16px 18px;
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: 0.9;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
            border-radius: 80px;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisvikram/72XyL/236/